# 'currentTime' attribute is not working in HTML5 video in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video

I am trying to jump at a certain time in my video using HTML5 video player.
Code snippet:

```
z = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0]  //grab the video element
z.currentTime  //prints the current time
z.currentTime = 3 //should jump to 3 seconds, but going to 0 sec instead.
```

The above code is working fine in Firefox.

Comment: is the video encoded with the MOOV atom at the start or the end? if the video has had a chance to fully load does it work? If the answer to the first is "end" (default) and the second is "yes", then re-encode the video for faststart (moves the metadata to the beginning so it knows where 3 seconds in is)

Comment: If it's only Chrome and IF your file is fragmented, maybe you are hitting this bug ? https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=584203